# How to determine if a TreeView.SelectedNode is parent or child node

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, triggers, treeview

[image]I have a TreeView control in my ASP.NET web application, and I have problems with the event selected node changed, I click on some node in the treeview but the event doesn't trigger, I have some instructions there that are not executed, I checked with debugger also.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="ArboreSarcini" runat="server" ImageSet="News" 
onselectednodechanged="ArboreSarcini_SelectedNodeChanged" NodeIndent="10" 
style="z-index: 1; left: 1px; top: 27px; position: absolute; height: 308px; width: 446px">
<HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" BackColor="#99CCCC" Font-Size="12pt" />
<LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Poze/leaf.png" NodeSpacing="2px" />
<LevelStyles>
<asp:TreeNodeStyle BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
Font-Names="Leelawadee" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="False" 
ImageUrl="~/Poze/Root.png" />
<asp:TreeNodeStyle BorderColor="#003300" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
Font-Names="Leelawadee" Font-Underline="False" ImageUrl="~/Poze/node.png" 
Width="400px" />
<asp:TreeNodeStyle BorderColor="#006600" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
Font-Names="Leelawadee" Font-Underline="False" Height="10px" 
ImageUrl="~/Poze/leaf.png" Width="390px" />
</LevelStyles>
<NodeStyle Font-Names="Leelawadee" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Black" 
HorizontalPadding="5px" NodeSpacing="2px" VerticalPadding="0px" 
ImageUrl="~/Poze/node.png" Width="0px" />
<ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" Width="500px" />
<RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Poze/Root.png" />
<SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" BackColor="#009148" BorderWidth="2px" 
Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="12pt" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ArboreSarcini.Nodes.Clear();
populeaza_sarcini();

string sqlstring1 = "Select * from activitati";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
            "Data Source=BOGDAN-PC\\BOGDAN;Initial Catalog=ePlanning;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=10;TrustServerCertificate=True ");
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring1, con1);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader1;
con1.Open();
reader1 = comm1.ExecuteReader();

while (reader1.Read())
{
foreach (Sarcina s in listaSarcini)
{
    if ((int)reader1["id_sarcina"] == s.Id_sarcina)
    {
        s.ListaActivitati.Add(new Activitate(Convert.ToInt32(reader1["id_activitate"]), reader1["descriere"].ToString()));
    }
}
}

TreeNode tatal = new TreeNode();
tatal.Value = DropListProiecte.SelectedItem.ToString();
//    ArboreSarcini.Nodes.Add(tatal);


TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode();
foreach (Sarcina sarc in listaSarcini)
{
parentNode = new TreeNode( sarc.Id_sarcina.ToString() + ". " + sarc.Descriere.ToString());


foreach (Activitate act in sarc.ListaActivitati)
{
    TreeNode copil = new TreeNode(act.Id_activitate.ToString()+". "+act.Descriere.ToString() );
    parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(copil);
}
tatal.ChildNodes.Add(parentNode);
//parentNode.Collapse();


}
ArboreSarcini.Nodes.Add(tatal);
con.Close();
ArboreSarcini.ExpandAll();
}


    protected void ArboreSarcini_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (ArboreSarcini.SelectedNode.ImageUrl == "~/Poze/node.png")
    {

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
                      "Data Source=BOGDAN-PC\\BOGDAN;Initial Catalog=ePlanning;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=10;TrustServerCertificate=True ");
        //  string de_splituit = ArboreSarcini.SelectedNode.Text;
        string[] id_sarcina = ArboreSarcini.SelectedNode.Text.Split('.');


        string sqlstring = "Select * from sarcini where id_sarcina=" + id_sarcina[0] + ";";




        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring, con);
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;

        con.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tbIDSarcina.Text = reader["id_sarcina"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you populate your tree? perhaps you're doing this in each postback.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: yes, sorry if it's kind of messed up

Comment: If you put the breakpoint whether it hits the `ArboreSarcini_SelectedNodeChanged` event ?

Comment: yes, thanks, I've tried with breakpoints lower in the method, looks like it te event is triggered, my if (ArboreSarcini.SelectedNode.ImageUrl == "~/Poze/node.png") blocks the exection of following code, MY BAD, sorry, and THANKS, but I have the next question, how can I determine if i Click a parent node or a child node( I have cases when a parent node dosen't have any child)

Comment: can u please give a clear idea? You have provided 'Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)'. But the event supposed to fire is 'ArboreSarcini_SelectedNodeChanged'. Please edit the question

Comment: 'Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)' populates the TreeView, and When I select a node from the TreeView I would like to connect to a database and retrieve some info according to the treeview.selectednode.text

Comment: OK i can see the code. So you are saying that you can see the while debugging `ArboreSarcini_SelectedNodeChanged` is hitting and if condition executes. So what is the issue ?

Comment: I would like to know how to know if the selected node is a parent node, or a child node, should I ask another question?Thanks for all the help by the way, and patience:)

Comment: Yes you should ask another question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, the TreeView control handles expand-collapse functionality
>   on the client unless the browser does not support client script or the
>   EnableClientScript property is set to false. If the
>   PopulateNodesFromClient property is set to true and the browser
>   supports client script, then the TreeView control retrieves the data
>   from the server without posting the entire page back.
>
> When the TreeView control is in selection mode, each time a user
>   clicks a node, a postback to the server occurs and the
>   SelectedNodeChanged event is raised.
>
> Typically, you should handle postback events when the TreeView control
>   is in selection mode or the nodes are being dynamically populated.
>   This is because either the PopulateOnDemand or PopulateNodesFromClient
>   property is set to true.

So kindly verify that you set all the required properties. Sharing your HTML might helpful.
Read more about the asp.net treeview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z5184w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
TreeNode.Nodes Property.
Gets the collection of TreeNode objects assigned to the current tree node.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nodes.aspx

Comment: I think I found out what was the problem, the event was triggered but, my other instructions blocked the following code, and I've debbuged with breakpoint too low in the code, thanks! good info though

Comment: i can't see your image. because of some restrictions in my office. SO the code might be very helpful to understand

Comment: I've provided all the code...moments ago ,It dosen't appear? I was wondering why you are still asking about the code...

Comment: can u provide the code , similar way u provided the html. Due to some  restrictions in my office I can;t able to see the image

Comment: all code for the treeview are now updated(Button that triggers the populating of the treeview, HTML code, and eventhandler for SelectedNodeChanged)